# C Ctrl+D redirection to do smtg else

Tags: c, signals

I am writting a program that copy the bash behaviour,

I use a while loop that stop if a variable "stop" is filled.

I want to get the ctrl-D signal when I press Ctrl-D only to fill the variable stop instead of stopping everything, is it possible

```
#include <signal.h>

void sigint_do(int sig) //handle the crtl c signal                              
{                                                                               
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_do);                                                  
    sig = sig;                                                                  
    fflush(stdout);                                                                                                                     
} 

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_do);
    int stop = -1;
    while (stop < 0) 
        //do smg

    if (stop >= 0)
    {
        free all allocation needed;
        exit(stop);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i already use a signal handling for ctrl-C with signal.h but i don't understand how to do modify the variable "stop" in the signal handler function if the Ctrl-D is seen.

could you give me any tip please?

Comment: Control-D does not generate a signal.

Comment: Define it globally (as `sig_atomic_t stop =0;` )

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is not a signal. It is simply translated by the system to the EOF symbol.

You can detect it if the read() command returns 0 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readline(). It returns NULL when ctrl + D is pressed. (For me read worked not really well).

something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main ( void )
{
   char *line;

   line = readline(":");
   while(line)
   {
      line = readline(":");
   }
   return (0);
}
```